# NSPredicate filtering with NSManagedObject's helper method

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UITable view which contains a list of NSManagedObjects called Assignment. I am using NSPredicate to filter the list. 
I am filtering assignments that should be shown for today and yesterday for a player:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"player == %@ AND (day == %@ OR day == %@)", 
                          player, 
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self todaysDayNumber]],
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self yesterdaysDayNumber]]];
```

I need to add an additional level of filtering. I want to filter out assignments that should only be shown biweekly. So I added this methods to Assigment:

```
-(BOOL)thisWeeks{
  //If this is a weekly assigment
  if ([self.weekly boolValue]) {
    return YES;
  }

  //Determine the week number
  NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
  NSUInteger unitFlags = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
  NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags 
                                                 fromDate:[NSDate date]];
  NSUInteger week = [dateComponents week];

  //Assigned week even?
  if ([self.weekNumber intValue] % 2){
    //Current week even?
    if (week % 2) {
        return YES;
    }  
  } 
  //Assigned week odd?
  if (!week % 2) {
  //Current week odd?
    if (![self.weekNumber intValue] % 2){
      return YES;
    }
  }
//Should not be shown this week.
return NO;
}
```

is it possible to use this helper method "thisWeeks" as a filter in NSPredicate?

If I'm "doing it wrong", I could manually filter the fetched results, but I am unsure as to how I would put the results back into NSFetchedResultsController such that my UITable view could continue using NSFetchedResultsController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NSPredicate** also accepts blocks as predicates. Here an example with the first check in *thisWeeks*:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bind) {
    return [self.weekly boolValue];
}];
```

Now you can implement the method *- (BOOL)thisWeeksWithObject:(id)object* and write this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bind) {
    return [self thisWeeksWithObject:obj];
}];
```

Sure, you have to change the *self* in the method to *object*.

Comment: Looks like a good solution but **predicateWithBlock** requires IOS 4.0 or greater. Is there a way to not use predicateWithBlock?

Comment: I think that you have to implement your custom method which iterates through all fetched objects and check if they are valid, if so, add it to an array and finally return the array with all checked objects. But this method is very slow compared to the **predicateWithBlock**.